# Importing GeoSPARQL in Protege

Tags: protege, geosparql

I am trying to build a new ontology which utilises some of the classes and properties. Therefore, I wanted to import the GeoSPARQL ontology in Protege. However, on using the URI given in the GeoSPARQL1.1 documentation, the Protege is not able to find the ontology. The URI I am using is as follows:
`http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql/1.1`.
I found a similar question on stackoverflow, where they have suggested to use the following URI:
`http://schemas.opengis.net/geosparql/1.0/geosparql_vocab_all.rdf`, which works. However, this URI works for GeoSPARQL 1.0, not for 1.1.
Could anyone suggest why the URI given in the GeoSPARQL1.1 documentation is not working and how can I import it in Protege.

Thanks.

Comment: it is `https://opengeospatial.github.io/ogc-geosparql/geosparql11/geo.ttl` or not?